# Версия Python не отображается в cmd

Tags: python-3.x

помогите с python, не видит команду или не отображает версию.
Тут думаю заняться программированием на python установил правильно, в конце булы иконка с щитком (типо для win10 обязательно её нажимать - нажал.) Потом рещил проверить версию и тут такое.)

[image: Никакого ответа и привета на данную команду]

Comment: python нужно с маленькой буквы писать.

Comment: Это играет БОЛЬШУЮ роль?

Comment: python - -version (два минуса перед version без пробела)

Comment: Под Windows регистр букв в названиях файлов не имеет значения. Под *nix системами - имеет (python и Python там два разных имени файла).

Comment: Толку нет хоть с 1 хоть с 2мя.

Comment: Вообще у меня питон 32 битный, а система 64. В этом может быть проблема?